# Bash going crazy on Debian

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I'm a bit surprised, I have deployed a VM with Azure and when I SSH on it, I get a weird bash :

I have no cmdline prefix, where I used to have `username@host:~$`, it's empty.
I have no completion either.. Nothing changes when I type `bash`

Here is the /etc/passwd line for my user :

admusr:x:1000:1000::/home/admusr:/bin/bash

[image]

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Either PS1 got unset, or you accidentally redirected stderr.  Try typing `PS1='$ '` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: No changes unfortunatly

Comment: Then let's rule out my other idea -- try: `exec 2>/dev/tty`

Comment: `-bash: line 4: /dev/tty: No such device or address` when I type clear : `TERM environment variable not set.`

Comment: sorry for the false leads! One last try:  `exec 2>$(tty)`    --- sorry for the syntax highlighting mess. I wanted to use backticks to show the command, but `tty` also needs to be in backticks when you type it.

Comment: No change either for this one

Comment: Seems like the VM was damaged or infected.

Comment: This can happen if you don't have a TTY for `stdout` as well (not just `stderr`)... try forcing allocation of a TTY by running `ssh -t ...` when you connect... please also include the output of `echo $0` and `ls -l /proc/$$/fd/`

Comment: @Attie that's odd; wouldn't `ls`'s output (shown above) be going to stdout? It's clearly visible to the OP.

Comment: @jeff yes... but it doesn't have to be open as a TTY... it could be a simple pipe! (e.g: `ssh -T`)... come to think of it, if `ssh -t` doesn't work, try `ssh -tt`...

Answer (score 1):

This will typically happen when `stdin` is not a TTY. (I misspoke in the comments, this is unrelated to `stdout` or `stderr`).

The SSH client will automatically determine whether its `stdin` is a TTY, and will then request that the SSH server does or does not allocate a PTY for this session accordingly.

I suspect that your local shell doesn't have a TTY on `stdin`, or perhaps you're using `ssh` in a pipeline, etc... You probably want to fix that rather than override `ssh`'s behaviour (as below).

If you run `tty`, and the output is "*not a tty*" rather than a path like `/dev/pts/9`, then this will confirm my suspicions.

Try some the following on a fully functional termainal (substituting `ssh ${HOST}` for `bash` will give similar results):

- `ssh ${HOST}` - *should* give you a standard remote shell, with a prompt, history, etc...

  - Because your terminal's TTY / PTY is provided as `ssh`'s `stdin`.
- `cat | ssh ${HOST}` - *should* give you a "*muted*" shell as you are reporting

  - Because `cat`'s `stdout` (not a TTY) is provided as `ssh`'s `stdin`.

---

There are a few command line options to override this automatic behaviour:

- `ssh -t` - *request* allocation of a PTY on the server

  - `cat | ssh -t ${HOST}` will still result in a "*muted*" shell, and you'll see a message along the lines of "*Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.*"
- `ssh -tt` - *force* allocation of a PTY on the server

  - `cat | ssh -tt ${HOST}` will result in a session that initially appears to be "*good*", but you'll find that things are actually quite broken... `man ssh` won't fill the screen, control characters will hit the SSH client (or probably more accurately `cat`) not the remote application, etc...
- `ssh -T` - *disable* allocation of a PTY on the server

  - `ssh -T ${HOST}` will result in a "*muted*" shell

---

Consider running a shell script that is executable and has the following contents:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello"
echo "world"
```

What actually happens in this situation is that `/bin/bash` is executed, with the file provided as `stdin` (not your terminal). `bash` will detect that `stdin` is not a TTY, and will suppress certain behaviours, such as printing a prompt between commands and recording the commands in your history.